# sql data save query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to save new data from access tables to sql tables without overwriting old data in sql. Data table format for access and sql is same.(using Visual Basic)

Comment: What do you want to do for the conflicts? First how do you define a _conflict_?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique id on the row, then you can check whether the value is already in the database (logically equivalent to this):

```
insert into data_table dt
select * from access_table a
where a.id not in (select id from data_table)
```

A unique id, of course, is any subset of fields in the row, identifying a unique row.